# Calculating the difference between $f(x+iy)$ and $f(x-iy)$ when $y\to0+$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, branch-cuts

I have asked [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721441/approaching-the-branch-cut-and-the-limit-of-fxiy-when-y-to0) about the limit of two functions as they're approaching the real axis before. Today I considered the function $f(z)=\sqrt{1-z^2}$, trying to calculate the difference in similar way.

The function have two branch points $z=\pm1$. When it takes value above the line segment $(-1,1)$, I split it into two parts $-1<x<0$ and $0<x<1$. I chose the principal value of $f(z)$ and let $-\pi<\text{arg}(z)\leq\pi$.
\begin{equation}
f(z)=\sqrt{1-z^2}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\log(1-z^2)}=e^{\frac{1}{2}(\log(\mid 1-z^2\mid)+i\text{arg}(1-z^2))}
\end{equation}
Substitute $z=x+iy$, then $f(x+iy)=\sqrt{\mid1-x^2+y^2\mid}e^{\frac{i}{2}\text{arg}(1-x^2+y^2-2ixy)}$. When $y\to0+$, the magnitude tends to $\sqrt{1-x^2},x\in(-1,1)$, and the argument becomes
\begin{equation}
\text{arg}(1-x^2+y^2-2ixy)=
\begin{cases}
0-, & 0<x<1\\
0+, & -1<x<0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
So the limit of $f(x+iy)$ as $z=x+iy$ approaching the line segment $(-1,1)$ is always $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Do another similar operation to $f(x-iy)$ as $y\to0+$, $f(z)=\sqrt{\mid 1-x^2+y^2\mid}e^{\frac{i}{2}\text{arg}(1-x^2+y^2+2ixy)}$, we have
\begin{equation}
\text{arg}(1-x^2+y^2+2ixy)=
\begin{cases}
0+, & 0<x<1\\
0-, & -1<x<0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
It comes out the same result as previous one. So the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{y\to0+}(f(x+iy)-f(x-iy))=0,\ -1<x<1
\end{equation}
exists and is identically zero. Is this solution feasible? Can we have better methods?

P.S.: The [visualization](https://samuelj.li/complex-function-plotter/#sqrt(1-z%5E2)) shows the same result.

P.P.S.: I also calculated the situation when $x>1$ and $x<-1$, the difference when $y\to0+$ should be
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-2i\sqrt{\mid 1-x^2\mid}, & x>1\\
2i\sqrt{\mid 1-x^2\mid}, &x<-1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: In Wikipedia, you should look at  'Hilbert transform.'